# Jquery simple function

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

The aim of this code is to delete a comment with AJAX.  The function is called as follows:

```
DeleteComment(166);
```

And the code that runs is:

```
// Each delete button
function DeleteComment(CommentID) {

    $.ajax({
        url: AJAXURL + "?action=del&id=" + CommentID,
        success: function (data) {

            // Parse the data
            if (data.substring(0, 1) == "1") {

                $('#cid' + CommentID).hide();

            } else {
                alert(data.substring(2, data.length));
            }
        }
    });

}
```

However the `$('#cid' + CommentID).hide();` line never fires as `CommentID` isn't retained, I'm new to Jquery, could someone show me how to change this so the comments ID is retained when the ajax success is called?

Comment: Do you have html element with the id="cid166" ? view the rendered html source and search for cid166

Comment: do you get to the point after the if statement?

Comment: @Tom Gullen what is in the response?

Comment: @fatn lol my bad, thanks, it was a reference element, .parent() fixed it to hide the container thanks :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

put the     `$('#cid' + CommentID).hide();` before `$.ajax({` and then add  `$('#cid' + CommentID).show();` to your else condition..

Hide it first and then reshow it if deletion fails...

Not the most graceful solution, but the path of least resistance from where you are.

Comment: it will bump the browser... I dont think this is a good solution

Comment: @fatnjazzy, "bump the browser"? If that means what I think it does (cause the UI to jump) then only if there is some error with the attempt to delete on the server, and then it would be a good way to draw attention to it...

Answer (score 1):

Can you post more of the surrounding code? As is, your code looks like it should work.  But I see a troublesome comment: `// Each delete button`.  The way you are binding the DeleteComment function to the buttons must not be working the way you assume.

Try this instead:

```
// Iterate over each delete button.  
// The .each(...) provides you a function, a.k.a. local scope, for each button.
$(".deleteButtons").each(function (idx, el) {

    // This is very important: you must create a local variable to hold the ID.
    // How to get the ID is up to you.
    var id = getTheCorrespondingCommentId(idx, el); 

    // Now you can safely pass the local variable to the DeleteComment function:
    $(el).click(function() { DeleteComment(id); });
});
```